# I need a help on manipulating this logarithmic expression

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

How do I approach this problem is the difficulty for me. If I can get a headstart then I'll be able to finished it from there. I got this problem for a junior at school, it say
if $\log_3 (x-6) = 2y$ and
$\log_2 (x-7) = 3y$

Show that $x^2 - 13x + 42 = 72^y$.

Now, from my own end I don't know what step to take that will lead me to the answer. Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: $\log_b(u)=v\iff u=b^v.$

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried it that way but I ended up in deadlock

Comment: Additional hints: $(x-6)(x-7)=\dots$? and $b^{kv}=(b^k)^v.$ If you still can't conclude, type what you tried.

Comment: Thanks. I think I can proceed from here

Answer (score -1, accepted):

well, from the definition of log, we obtain
$$
\left\{
\begin{align*}
x - 6 &= 3^{2y} = 9^y \\
x - 7 &= 2^{3y} = 8^y
\end{align*}
\right.
$$

multiply both sides instantly generates what's desired.

Comment: Got it! Thanks, I can finish it from here

Comment: I refrained from giving such an answer because for that kind of questions, I think less extensive hints are more pedagogical.

Comment: but the very idea of the website is about ask & answer, see [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour)